# Row_Number() with union query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have an sql query that returns rows from two tables with same column names. I need a row number of all records in a complete result set.

Following is the query

```
select Id, VersionNumber from documents where id=5 
Union all  
select Id, VersionNumber from versions where id=5
order by VersionNumber desc
```

How should it be done?

**EDIT:** And what if I only need to return a row_num where VersionNumber is lets say 5.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) ROW_NUM
  FROM (
        select Id, VersionNumber from documents where id=5 
        Union all  
        select Id, VersionNumber from versions where id=5
       ) a
order by VersionNumber desc
```

TO filter by version number 5 use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY versionnumber DESC, id) row_num 
        FROM   (SELECT id, 
                       versionnumber 
                FROM   documents 
                WHERE  id = 5 
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT id, 
                       versionnumber 
                FROM   versions 
                WHERE  id = 5) a) b 
WHERE  version = 5
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can you please also tell how to return a row_num where VersionNumber is lets say 5?

Comment: You r filtering the records where version=5 currently.

Comment: no, its being filtered on id. For id=5, we'll have multiple versions. I need to find the index of version=5 in complete resultset

Comment: this query determines the row_num before the result set is ordered by version number in desc. How can I execute a where clause after order by.

Comment: but how can you also filter by row number? for example adding where row_num > 10 to the first query above this won't work

Comment: @Para: You can use the second query and add the row_num > 10 criteria.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly better way would be :-

```
with resultset1 as(
   select Id, VersionNumber from documents where id=5 
   Union all  
   select Id, VersionNumber from versions where id=5
), resultset2 as(
   select Id, VersionNumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) ROW_NUM
   from resultset1
)
select * from resultset2 WHERE VersionNumber = 5
```