# Row_number function over union all in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

So this is my code below :

```
SELECT 
    DV.ERSDataValues_ERSCommodity_ID AS Commodity_ID,
    SU.ERSSector_Desc AS Sector,
    GU.ERSGroup_Desc AS Group_Description,
    CSC.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_Desc AS CommodityName,
    STU.ERSStatisticType_Attribute AS Statistic_Type,
    SLU.ERSSource_Desc AS Source,
    CDS.ERSCommodity_PhysicalAttribute_Desc AS Physical_Attribute,
    UPU.ERSUtilPractice_Desc AS Util_Practice,
    PU.ERSProdPractice_Desc AS Production_Practice,
    TDT.ERSTimeDimensionType_Desc AS Time_Frequency,
    TU.ERSTimeDimension_Date AS [Date],
    GTU.ERSGeographyType_Desc AS Geography_Type,
    GDU.ERSGeographyDimension_Desc AS Geography_Dimension,
    ULU.ERSUnit_Desc AS Unit_Description,
    DV.ERSDataValues_AttributeValue AS [Value]
FROM
    CoSD.ERSCommodityDataSeries AS CDS
INNER JOIN 
    CoSD.ERSDataValues AS DV ON CDS.ERSCommodity_ID = DV.ERSDataValues_ERSCommodity_ID
INNER JOIN 
    CoSD.ERSSector_LU AS SU ON CDS.ERSCommodity_ERSSector_ID = SU.ERSSector_ID
INNER JOIN 
    CoSD.ERSGroup_LU AS GU ON CDS.ERSCommodity_ERSGroup_ID = GU.ERSGroup_ID
INNER JOIN 
    CoSD.ERSProdPractice_LU AS PU ON CDS.ERSCommodity_ERSProdPractice_ID = PU.ERSProdPractice_ID
INNER JOIN 
    CoSD.ERSUtilPractice_LU AS UPU ON CDS.ERSCommodity_ERSUtilPractice_ID = UPU.ERSUtilPractice_ID
                                          AND CDS.ERSCommodity_ERSUtilPractice_ID = UPU.ERSUtilPractice_ID
INNER JOIN 
    CoSD.ERSUnit_LU AS ULU ON DV.ERSDataValues_ERSUnit_ID = ULU.ERSUnit_ID
INNER JOIN 
    CoSD.ERSSource_LU AS SLU ON CDS.ERSCommodity_ERSSource_ID = SLU.ERSSource_ID
INNER JOIN 
    CoSD.ERSStatisticType_LU AS STU ON CDS.ERSCommodity_ERSStatisticType_ID = STU.ERSStatisticType_ID
INNER JOIN 
    CoSD.ERSTimeDimension_LU AS TU ON DV.ERSDataValues_ERSTimeDimension_ID = TU.ERSTimeDimension_ID
INNER JOIN 
    CoSD.ERSGeographyDimension_LU AS GDU ON DV.ERSDataValues_ERSGeography_ID = GDU.ERSGeographyDimension_ID
INNER JOIN 
    CoSD.ERSTimeDimensionType_LU AS TDT ON TU.ERSTimeDimension_TimeDimensionType_ID = TDT.ERSTimeDimensionType_ID
INNER JOIN 
    CoSD.ERSGeographyType_LU AS GTU ON GDU.ERSGeographyDimension_ERSGeographyType_ID = GTU.ERSGeographyType_ID
INNER JOIN 
    CoSD.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_LU AS CSC ON CSC.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_ID=CDS.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT cds.ERSCommodity_ID AS Commodity_ID
      ,slu.ERSSector_Desc AS Sector
      ,glu.ERSGroup_Desc AS Group_Description
      ,csc.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_Desc AS CommodityName
      ,stu.ERSStatisticType_Attribute_Desc
      ,CVO.ERSConstructedVariable_InputSources
      ,cds.ERSCommodity_PhysicalAttribute_Desc
      ,ulu.ERSUtilPractice_Desc
      ,plu.ERSProdPractice_Desc
      ,CVO.ERSConstructedVariable_OutputTimeDimensionValue
      ,CVO.ERSConstructedVariable_TimeDimensionDate
      ,gtlu.ERSGeographyType_Desc
      ,gdlu.ERSGeographyDimension_Country
      ,unlu.ERSUnit_Desc
      ,CVO.ERSConstructedVariable_OutputValue
FROM CoSD.ERSConstructedVariablesOutcomes AS CVO
INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSCommodityDataSeries AS cds ON CVO.ERSConstructedVariable_NewDataSeriesID = cds.ERSCommodity_ID
INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSSector_LU AS slu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSSector_ID = slu.ERSSector_ID
INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSGroup_LU AS glu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSGroup_ID = glu.ERSGroup_ID
INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_LU AS csc ON cds.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_ID = csc.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_ID
INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSStatisticType_LU AS stu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSStatisticType_ID = stu.ERSStatisticType_ID
INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSUtilPractice_LU AS ulu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSUtilPractice_ID = ulu.ERSUtilPractice_ID
INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSProdPractice_LU AS plu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSProdPractice_ID = plu.ERSProdPractice_ID
INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSGeographyDimension_LU AS gdlu ON CVO.ERSConstructedVariable_OutputGeographyDimensionID = gdlu.ERSGeographyDimension_ID
INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSUnit_LU AS unlu ON CVO.ERSConstructedVariable_OutputUnitID = unlu.ERSUnit_ID
INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSGeographyType_LU AS gtlu ON gdlu.ERSGeographyDimension_ERSGeographyType_ID = gtlu.ERSGeographyType_ID
WHERE (CVO.ERSConstructedVariable_DataRowPrivacyID = 1)
```

I want to add the row number function so that I get an unique ID for each row,
I tried this way in this link 
[Row_Number() with union query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190240/row-number-with-union-query)
but it did not work, any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work?  Looks to be a duplicate of the link you posted.  Just change `order by id` to `order by commodity_id`...

Comment: yeah ofcourse I changed it to that, it throws an error at the closing paranthesis,says incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: Did you include the ending table alias after the closing `)`?  `select *, row_number() over (order by commodity_id) rn from (your query) t`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you **don't** use [source] or [date] as column aliases, and also in a where clause you don't need to surround each predicate with parentheses.

What I cannot verify is that all the column data types are compatible, but the query should look something like this:

```
SELECT
    commodity_id
  , sector
  , group_description
  , commodityname
  , statistic_type
  , [source]
  , physical_attribute
  , util_practice
  , production_practice
  , time_frequency
  , [date]
  , geography_type
  , geography_dimension
  , unit_description
  , value
  , row_number() over(order by commodity_id) as rn
FROM (
        SELECT
            dv.ERSDataValues_ERSCommodity_ID        AS commodity_id
          , su.ERSSector_Desc                       AS sector
          , gu.ERSGroup_Desc                        AS group_description
          , csc.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_Desc       AS commodityname
          , stu.ERSStatisticType_Attribute          AS statistic_type
          , slu.ERSSource_Desc                      AS source
          , cds.ERSCommodity_PhysicalAttribute_Desc AS physical_attribute
          , upu.ERSUtilPractice_Desc                AS util_practice
          , pu.ERSProdPractice_Desc                 AS production_practice
          , tdt.ERSTimeDimensionType_Desc           AS time_frequency
          , tu.ERSTimeDimension_Date                AS date
          , gtu.ERSGeographyType_Desc               AS geography_type
          , gdu.ERSGeographyDimension_Desc          AS geography_dimension
          , ulu.ERSUnit_Desc                        AS unit_description
          , dv.ERSDataValues_AttributeValue         AS value
        FROM CoSD.ERSCommodityDataSeries AS cds
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSDataValues AS dv ON cds.ERSCommodity_ID = dv.ERSDataValues_ERSCommodity_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSSector_LU AS su ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSSector_ID = su.ERSSector_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSGroup_LU AS gu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSGroup_ID = gu.ERSGroup_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSProdPractice_LU AS pu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSProdPractice_ID = pu.ERSProdPractice_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSUtilPractice_LU AS upu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSUtilPractice_ID = upu.ERSUtilPractice_ID
            AND cds.ERSCommodity_ERSUtilPractice_ID = upu.ERSUtilPractice_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSUnit_LU AS ulu ON dv.ERSDataValues_ERSUnit_ID = ulu.ERSUnit_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSSource_LU AS slu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSSource_ID = slu.ERSSource_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSStatisticType_LU AS stu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSStatisticType_ID = stu.ERSStatisticType_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSTimeDimension_LU AS tu ON dv.ERSDataValues_ERSTimeDimension_ID = tu.ERSTimeDimension_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSGeographyDimension_LU AS gdu ON dv.ERSDataValues_ERSGeography_ID = gdu.ERSGeographyDimension_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSTimeDimensionType_LU AS tdt ON tu.ERSTimeDimension_TimeDimensionType_ID = tdt.ERSTimeDimensionType_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSGeographyType_LU AS gtu ON gdu.ERSGeographyDimension_ERSGeographyType_ID = gtu.ERSGeographyType_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_LU AS csc ON csc.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_ID = cds.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_ID

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            cds.ERSCommodity_ID               AS commodity_id
          , slu.ERSSector_Desc                AS sector
          , glu.ERSGroup_Desc                 AS group_description
          , csc.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_Desc AS commodityname
          , stu.ERSStatisticType_Attribute_Desc
          , cvo.ERSConstructedVariable_InputSources
          , cds.ERSCommodity_PhysicalAttribute_Desc
          , ulu.ERSUtilPractice_Desc
          , plu.ERSProdPractice_Desc
          , cvo.ERSConstructedVariable_OutputTimeDimensionValue
          , cvo.ERSConstructedVariable_TimeDimensionDate
          , gtlu.ERSGeographyType_Desc
          , gdlu.ERSGeographyDimension_Country
          , unlu.ERSUnit_Desc
          , cvo.ERSConstructedVariable_OutputValue
        FROM CoSD.ERSConstructedVariablesOutcomes AS cvo
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSCommodityDataSeries AS cds ON cvo.ERSConstructedVariable_NewDataSeriesID = cds.ERSCommodity_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSSector_LU AS slu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSSector_ID = slu.ERSSector_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSGroup_LU AS glu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSGroup_ID = glu.ERSGroup_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_LU AS csc ON cds.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_ID = csc.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSStatisticType_LU AS stu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSStatisticType_ID = stu.ERSStatisticType_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSUtilPractice_LU AS ulu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSUtilPractice_ID = ulu.ERSUtilPractice_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSProdPractice_LU AS plu ON cds.ERSCommodity_ERSProdPractice_ID = plu.ERSProdPractice_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSGeographyDimension_LU AS gdlu ON cvo.ERSConstructedVariable_OutputGeographyDimensionID = gdlu.ERSGeographyDimension_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSUnit_LU AS unlu ON cvo.ERSConstructedVariable_OutputUnitID = unlu.ERSUnit_ID
        INNER JOIN CoSD.ERSGeographyType_LU AS gtlu ON gdlu.ERSGeographyDimension_ERSGeographyType_ID = gtlu.ERSGeographyType_ID
        WHERE cvo.ERSConstructedVariable_DataRowPrivacyID = 1
    ) AS derived
```